# unable to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath after edit button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
IBOutlet _tableView;

-(IBAction)EditButton{

    NSLog(@"editButtonPressed");
    editing= !editing;
    [_tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];
   }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    tasklist *task=[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if(editing){
    TaskListEditorController *editor=[[TaskListEditorController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TaskListEditorController" bundle:nil];

    editor.defaulttext=task.prptext;

    editor.delegate=self;

    [self presentModalViewController:editor animated:YES];

    [editor release];

}else{


task.prpcompleted= !task.prpcompleted;

[tableView reloadData];

}
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

i am trying on xcode3.2.6 i am able to call when i dont put [_tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES]; on edit click but if i put it didselectrowatindexpath is not called please help

Comment: Frankly I do not understand your question. Please re-phrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the allowsSelectionDuringEditing property of your tableview to YES.

`_tableView.myTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;`